# Filtering in high level rest java elasticsearch client over multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to filter over a few fields.

All is ok if I filter over one but adding the second one gives wrong results.
Fields are `REQ_ID` and `CATEGORY`

In Kibana, following will return expected results

```
REQ_ID: '1574778361496' and CATEGORY: 'WARNING'
```

In java, I tried with:

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
final SimpleQueryStringBuilder sqb = QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery("REQ_ID: '1574778361496' and CATEGORY: 'WARNING'");
searchSourceBuilder.query(sqb);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

This yields results equivalent to upper having `or` instead of `and`, logically.

I also tried:

```
final BoolQueryBuilder bool = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
   .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("REQ_ID", "1574778361496"))
   .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("CATEGORY", "WARNING"))
   ;
searchSourceBuilder.query(bool);
```

This yields no results.

Not sure if this is a bug due to strange nature of `high rest java client` or am I reading the wrong manual?

client version: 7.4.2

elk version(sebp/elk:740): 7.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kibana use the [Kibana Query Language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/kuery-query.html) which is a little different of the Lucene language.
You can switch to Lucene on the top right of Kibana.
But you need no use the correct Lucene syntax (both in kibana with lucene syntax and in your java code), with upper operators :

```
REQ_ID: 'id1' AND CATEGORY: 'WARNING'
              ^^^
```

And you must use a `QueryStringQueryBuilder` instead of a `SimpleQueryStringBuilder` :

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
final QueryStringQueryBuilder sqb = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("REQ_ID: 'id1' and CATEGORY: 'WARNING'");
searchSourceBuilder.query(sqb);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the SimpleQueryString query for your use-case. Using a `TermQuery` is fine. I recommend to use the un-analyzed field in this case since you are only matching on an exact value. You could wrap this in a `Bool` clause within `filter` clauses. Example:

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("REQ_ID.keyword", "1574778361496"))
                .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("CATEGORY.keyword", "WARNING"));
```

Comment: You are right, `filter` clauses also work and are probably better with your data. I'll update my answer. I recommend to use this query instead of the QueryString query answer, because this one will perform better.